# how to make an array repeat after it has been exausted

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have this array (for background div color) going and I got it to work one time but that is as far as it goes... Any help would be appreciated.

```
$(function(){

// console.log('Hello, I am working');

var App = {
init: function(){
  // var Colors = ['red', 'blue', 'yellow', 'green', 'pink', 'orange'];
  // console.log('Hello, I am working');
  App.colorLinks();
},
colorLinks: function(){
  // $('body').find('a').addClass('love');
  // console.log(this.parent)
  var Colors = ['red', 'blue', 'yellow', 'green', 'pink', 'orange'];
  for (var i = 0; i < Colors.length; i++) {
    var AnchorList = $('a').length;
    for (var i = 0; i < AnchorList; i++) {
      $('body').find("a:eq("+i+")").addClass(Colors[i]);
    };
    // $('body').find('a').addClass(Colors[i]);
  };
  // console.log($('a').length);
}
};

App.init();

});
```

Comment: `Colors[i % Colors.length]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two common approaches are to use the remainder operator % or a simple if check:

```
 var links = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.links,0);
 links.forEach(function(link,i){
      link.classList.add(Colors[i % Colors.length])); // using remainder
 });
```

With an if check:

```
var j = 0;
for(var i =0; i < document.links.length; i++, j++){
    document.links[i].classList.add(colors[j]);
    if(j === Colors.length) j = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var Colors = ['red', 'blue', 'yellow', 'green', 'pink', 'orange'];

$.each('a', function(i,v){
    $(this).addClass(Colors[i % Colors.length]);
});
```

keep in mind this will cycle, but it may not exactly match the expected beginning since length is not 0 index based, but i will be. Plus, using modulus will return the remainder. In the end, you will get a cycling color array so maybe none of those details matter.

Comment: Kai Qing Thank you for your guidance I exhausted my ideas